# Construct bipartite graph from columns of python dataframe

Tags: python, graph, dataframe, networkx

I have a dataframe with three columns.

```
data['subdomain'],  data['domain'], data ['IP']
```

I want to build one bipartite graph for every element of subdomain that
corresponds to the same domain, and the weight to be the number of times that it
corresponds.

For example my data could be:

```
subdomain , domain, IP
test1, example.org, 10.20.30.40
something, site.com, 30.50.70.90
test2, example.org, 10.20.30.41
test3, example.org, 10.20.30.42
else, website.com, 90.80.70.10
```

I want a bipartite graph stating that `example.org` has a weight of 3 as it has
3 edges on it etc. And I want to group these results together into a new
dataframe.

I have been trying with **networkX** but I have no experience especially when the edges need to be computed.

```
B=nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from(data['subdomain'],bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(data['domain'],bipartite=1)
B.add_edges_from (...)
```

Comment: @lolkos you are probably having the wrong idea about what weights in a graph represent. they represent the strength of connection between two nodes. If you want to know the number of connections falling on a node, just find the degree of that node, and you can also easily find which nodes it shares its edges with. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use

```
B.add_weighted_edges_from(
    [(row['domain'], row['subdomain'], 1) for idx, row in df.iterrows()], 
    weight='weight')
```

to add weighted edges, or you could use

```
B.add_edges_from(
    [(row['domain'], row['subdomain']) for idx, row in df.iterrows()])
```

to add edges without weights.

You may not need weights since the node degree is the number of edges adjacent
to that node. For example,

```
>>> B.degree('example.org')
3
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'IP': ['10.20.30.40',
      '30.50.70.90',
      '10.20.30.41',
      '10.20.30.42',
      '90.80.70.10'],
     'domain': ['example.org',
      'site.com',
      'example.org',
      'example.org',
      'website.com'],
     'subdomain': ['test1', 'something', 'test2', 'test3', 'else']})

B = nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from(df['subdomain'], bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(df['domain'], bipartite=1)
B.add_weighted_edges_from(
    [(row['domain'], row['subdomain'], 1) for idx, row in df.iterrows()], 
    weight='weight')

print(B.edges(data=True))
# [('test1', 'example.org', {'weight': 1}), ('test3', 'example.org', {'weight': 1}), ('test2', 'example.org', {'weight': 1}), ('website.com', 'else', {'weight': 1}), ('site.com', 'something', {'weight': 1})]

pos = {node:[0, i] for i,node in enumerate(df['domain'])}
pos.update({node:[1, i] for i,node in enumerate(df['subdomain'])})
nx.draw(B, pos, with_labels=False)
for p in pos:  # raise text positions
    pos[p][1] += 0.25
nx.draw_networkx_labels(B, pos)

plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

---

Comment: Yes but with this way, we define the weight to 1... I wanted something to count how many times "example.org" has been querried and then give it the weight of 3 , as the edges that go to example.org