# Python how to choose what to print in a networkX graph

Tags: python, graph, dataframe, networkx

I have a graph that shows the connection of subdomains with their domains, but I want to select only the domains that are being queried more than 10 times.

```
B=nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from(data['subdomain'],bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(data['domain'],bipartite=1)
B.add_edges_from([(row['subdomain'] , row['domain']) for idx,row in data.iterrows()])


print (B.degree(data['domain']).items())
```

and

```
print (B.degree(data['domain']).values())
```

give me the values that I need, but I dont know how to use them in order to produce the graph only with those ***data['domain']*** values that are higher than a threshold (for example 10).

The rest of the code for the graph construction:

```
pos = {node:[0, i] for i,node in enumerate(data['domain'])}
pos.update({node:[1, i] for i,node in enumerate(data['subdomain'])})
nx.draw(B, pos, with_labels=False)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(B, pos)
plt.show
```

NOTE: Would be easier to select those values before constructing the graph and how is this possible? I mean, to select values from one dataframe column that correspond to many values from another dataframe column.

**EDIT:** So , I have these two dataframe columns , and the main idea is to try to find which domain names are being mapped by some subdomains more than 10 times, and then select these domain names and further process them.

So after `B.add_edges_from([(row['subdomain'] , row['domain']) for idx,row in data.iterrows()])` i get my graph which looks chaotic due to the big amount of data.
First of all, I want to show on my graph only the nodes that have more than 10 edges , and then from that new graph , I want to be able to select/store these domain names/nodes into a new dataframe.
What bothers me , is that I dont know if it is possible to select data out of a graph or not!

Comment: Suggestion: export your graph to `gexf` ([link](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/readwrite.gexf.html)) and do the job with a visualization tool like Gephi. I'm facing a problem which essentially is like yours and trying to get it solve this way. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see what is in `data` and purely judging by the way the code is written at the moment, it appears to be simply relating subdomains to domains in a simple Graph and therefore `B.degree([bunch of nodes])` would return a dictionary whose keys are nodes and the values are node degrees.

If all you are trying to do is induce a subgraph C from your original B whose nodes will be the domains with more than 10 subdomains, then you can do something like:

```
C = B.subgraph(filter(lambda x:x[1]>10, B.degree(data['domain']).items()))
```

Which is basically using [subgraph](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html) to induce C with the degree criterion being enforced by Python's filter.

Keep in mind however that in a bipartite graph, this is likely to simply return a set of nodes, because B associates subdomains with domains and the domains themselves will not have any connection between them.

If you are trying to retrieve the domains that have more than 10 subdomains and depict this later on as a set of star graphs (a domain in the middle with all of its subdomains around it), then the easiest way to retrieve those graphs would be to run a [dfs_tree](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_tree) (or a [bfs_tree](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_tree)).

If on the other hand, `data` contains one line for each "hit" of the domain by one of its subdomains then this means that more than one edges between a pair of subdomain / domain would be required and for this reason you would need to start with a [Multigraph](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/classes.multigraph.html) rather than a Graph.

Hope this helps, happy to amend the response if more details about `data` or the actual problem being dealt with are provided.

**EDIT**:
In view of additional comments and [earlier relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850688/construct-bipartite-graph-from-columns-of-python-dataframe/30852029#30852029), it is not clear if you want to proceed with a graph based solution or not.

If you want to proceed with a graph based solution, then the response above will filter those root domains which have more than a number of subdomains attached on them.

You can, of course, do the same thing using a pandas DataFrame with something like:

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("testFile.csv", index_col=False, header = None)
dataGrouped = data.groupby(1).count() #Group by domain and count the values in the other fields
busyDomains = dataGrouped[dataGrouped[0]>2]
```

With the `testFile.csv` having columns: subdomain, domain, ip

`busyDomains` is now another DataFrame. The main result here, using the test data on your previous question is "example.org".

Hope this helps.

Comment: So `data` is a dataframe with columns `domainName` , `domain` , `subdomain`and others like `lenght`...

One example could be **abc123.example.org**, **example.org**, **abc123** or **def456.example.org**, **example.org**, **def456**.

So in my graph , _example.org_ would have 2 edges coming from _abc123_ and _def456_.

If we suppose that _example.org_ has 15 edges I would like to be able to select _example.org_ and other domains like it with more than 10 edges coming in the node, and further process them. 

So I dont actually know if its a graph problem or if I can deal with it otherwise!

Comment: So the results from `(B.degree(data['domain']).items())` gives me sthing like : `('ubuntu', 5),('google-analytics', 20),('topdns', 12),('forbes', 16)`.


I want to be able to choose those 3 domains that have more than 10 subdomains mapping to them as the graph showed to me , and store them in another dataframe or column so that I can continue with my processing with only those values.

Comment: Thank you for the additional comments, please see amended response.

Comment: Thanks for the response and your time. Yes i know about `df.groupby` option. I was looking for sthing more like graph solution , where after adding the nodes and the edges, maybe i could keep in the graph only those nodes that have more than 20 edges , and then somehow store these nodes in a list or a dataframe column. But I guess if I first do the `groupby` and then construct the graph i will get sthing close to what I want!

Comment: Yes, looks like you might have to use a mixture of the two approaches. Happy to amend the response if you share some more information about what you exactly try to do. In the meantime please consider up voting/ accepting this response if you found it helped you.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. I edit my initial question, which is summarized in whether you can select actual data out of a visualised graph!