# NetworkX bipartite graph issues

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, networkx, bipartite, graph-coloring

Here's the set up: I have a data frame, `df`, with columns labeled A,B,...,K. Each entry of column A is unique and will make up one of the two sets of vertices, call it X, in a bipartite graph, `G`. The entries of columns B,...,K (not all unique) make up the other set of vertices, call it Y, in the bipartite graph. We draw an edge from vertex y in Y to vertex x in X if y is in the same row as x.

Using [this answer from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30852029/9409316), I have the following code which creates a bipartite graph with vertex sets given by the entries of column A (positioned on the right) and B (positioned on the left)

```
G = nx.Graph() 
G.add_nodes_from(df['A'], bipartite=0)
G.add_nodes_from(df['B'], bipartite=1)
G.add_weighted_edges_from(
    [(row['B'], row['A'], 1) for idx, row in df.iterrows()], 
    weight='weight')
pos = {node:[0, i] for i,node in enumerate(df['B'])}
pos.update({node:[1, i] for i,node in enumerate(df['A'])})
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels = True)
plt.show()
```

I'm seeking advice/help with a few problems:

1. The number of vertices is large enough so that the vertices appear very bunched up. Is there a way of spreading out the vertices in each of the two vertex sets?
2. As I mentioned, this code makes a bipartite graph connecting some entries of B with some entries of A (again, based on row matching). How can I do this for each of the other columns (i.e. connecting elements of C,...,K with A in the same way)? I know there is a way to union graphs together with `union(G1,G2)` but I imagine there's a better way to achieve this.
3. I'd like to create some kind of edge coloring based on the degree of vertices in Y. I imagine the coloring will be implemented using the `G.degree()`, but I'm not sure how that works.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions for my problems. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the positions of the nodes you can play with `pos` by drawing nodes further away, e.g., `pos = {node:[0*i, i*i] for i,node in enumerate(df['B'])}`. Or draw the nodes smaller with `nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels = True, node_size=100)` (or both).